# Account sales order history get item images

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, customer-account

Inside the account, I want to edit the order history page (/sales/order/history/).
Currenty the items of the order are not loaded on this page.

How can I load the items of the specific order, to get the productimages.
I want to show the purchased productimages inside the order history table.

So I want to load the items inside the `<?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>`.

How can I achieve that?

I am running Magento 1.9.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for shows items in order history you can add following code inside

```
<?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
```

and Code is

```
<?php $orderId = $_order->getId(); 
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            $items = $order->getAllItems();
            foreach ($items as $itemId => $_item)
            {
                echo "Product Id = ".$_item->getProductId()."<br>";
                echo "Product Name = ".$_item->getName()."<br>";
                echo "Product Price = ".$_item->getPrice()."<br>";   
                echo "Product SKU = ".$_item->getSku()."<br>";
                echo "Ordered Qty = ".$_item->getQtyToInvoice()."<br>";
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
                $_proImage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getThumbnail() );
                echo "<img src=".$_proImage." />";
            }
        ?>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Great. But is displays all the images of Configurable products. can you please look to this. thanks